# Pass object data as FormData

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm receiving the data like this:

```
pert_submit: {systemId: "53183", pert-id: "176061", score: 0, q2c: "3\0", q2t: "", …}
```

Now I want to send this as FormData in my post call. I can't make use of HTML form for this purpose, so in the http post call the data as to be as

```
systemId: "53183", pert-id: "176061", score: 0, q2c: "3\0", q2t: ""
```

I tried using FormData as

```
 var form_data = new FormData();
            for ( var key in this.dataObject['pert_submit'] ) {
                form_data.append(key, this.dataObject['pert_submit'][key]);
            }
```

How can I achieve it, pass FormData in the above specified format

```
(systemId: "53183", pert-id: "176061", score: 0, q2c: "3\0", q2t: "")
```

Comment: That's not JSON, that's just regular JavaScript object data.

Comment: It should help you, in researching the problem to find more help, and others, because it's not JSON and those searching for help with actual JSON will find no help via this question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok

Comment: One thing you haven't shared in your question is what about your attempt is not working. That's how you construct `FormData` from key/value pairs. If you want to pass the data not as FormData, but in a JSON-like format, you'll need to construct the string manually... But you should discuss with the service folks the benefits of using a standard format, like JSON or FormData, rather than custom formats.

Comment: So getting past semantics, does the answer I posted below work for you?

Comment: Yes it has to go as systemId: "53183", pert-id: "176061", score: 0 inside formdata with post request, I can't ask service guys to change anything due to certain restrictions @Heretic Monkey

Comment: The format you want is *not* the form-data format. So if the encoding you get is different, this is 100% expected. Form-data is specifically for urlencoded forms, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Object.entires when I need the key and value rather than Object.keys.
You can use array destructuring in a .forEach loop to get both values in a clean way.

```
const data = {systemId: "53183", "pert-id": "176061", score: 0, q2c: "3\0", q2t: "" };
const formData = new FormData();

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => formData.append(key, value))

console.log([...formData.entries()]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to pass it as systemId: "53183", pert-id: "176061", score: 0 in formdata, but with above solution the format is different

Comment: All non-string, non-blob data types are automatically converted to strings by the FormData api. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Answer (score 0):

Been there with service guys that can't change; as mentioned in the comments, you have to create the string manually. Here's one way.

Note that to add to `FormData`, you need a key. Here I've used "pert_submit" from the example data; you'll need to work out what it should be with the service folk. You may also want to look at writing directly to the body of the request via `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`, which is a bit more challenging.

```js
const data = {systemId: "53183", "pert-id": "176061", score: 0, q2c: "3\0", q2t: "" };
const getStringIfString = (val) => JSON.stringify(val);
const formattedOutput = Object.entries(data).reduce((agg, [key, val]) => `${agg}${agg.length ? ', ' : ''}${key}: ${getStringIfString(val)}`, "");
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('pert_submit', formattedOutput);
console.log(formattedOutput);
```

One last thing to note: The value `"3\0"` is interpreted by JavaScript as the number 3 followed by a NUL character; that's why the log of the output here may seem a little odd.

Comment: Would it be good idea, to add the key and values as dynamic  elements in form and then serialize form?